# how to downgrade mysql on Debian 10 from 8.029 to 8.02x

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, debian, downgrade

I have MySQL installed on my test server (Debian 10). I recently updated it to the newest version (8.0.29), but there are some issues with it so I want to go back to an older version (8.0.28). But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do so.

I have removed the existing database, and tried to re-install it using:

`apt-get install mysql-server=8.0.28-1debian10`

but that didn't work, and suggested I run:

`apt --fix-broken install`

which of course upgraded it to the latest version again.

I have tried numerous variations of this,but all result in `mysql-server can't be found` or similar errors.

I have been scouring the internet, and there seems to be lots of people asking similar questions, but no real solutions. Even the official MySQL documentation glosses over this bit.

Can it be done? And if so, how?
It's only a test database so I have no issues with scrapping it and starting again.

Comment: What sort of issues should people watch out for in this upgrade that affected you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got there in the end. This may not all be strictly correct, and there may be better ways to do this, however it works for me:

1. Take a MySQLDump backup first if required.
2. Remove the Old MySQL Version

`systemctl stop mysql`

`apt-get remove --purge 'mysql-.*'`

`apt-get autoremove`

`apt-get autoclean`

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

`rm -rf /etc/mysql`

`rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*`

3. Download the new version bundle

`cd /root`

`wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-server_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar`

4. extract the files and install in this order

`mkdir 828`

`tar -xvf mysql-server_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar -C /root/828`
`cd /root/828`
`dpkg -i libmysqlclient21_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-common_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-client-core_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-client_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-server-core_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`apt --fix-broken install`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-server-core_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-community-server_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-server_8.0.28-1debian10_amd64.deb`

It should now be working with the correct version:

`systemctl status mysql`

`mysqld- V`
`/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

Finally, secure the database
`mysql_secure_installation`

Answer (score 1):

If you have data first make a backup.

To completely uninstall `MySQL` follow below steps:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
```

To install `MySQL 8.0.22`  add the MySQL Software Repository

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnupg
```

Download `mysql-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar` from [MySQL archive](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/) or using wget :

```
wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
```

Once the download is completed install the package :

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*
```

During the installation, you’ll be presented with a configuration screen where you can specify which version of MySQL you’d prefer, along with an option to install repositories for other MySQL-related tools. Choose the one you need.

Refresh your apt package cache to make the new software packages available:

```
sudo apt update
```

Having added the repository and with your package cache freshly updated, now you can use apt to install the latest MySQL server package:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

MySQL should be installed and running now. Check by using systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

Do not forget to secure MySQL using

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

> Refrences
>
> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-properly-downgrade-from-mysql-8-to-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04
>
> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10

Comment: The only suggestion is that backup should be logical by mysqldump, not physical by xtrabackup, Physical backups can be not backward compatible with earlier versions of mysql.

Comment: Sadly, I followed these instructions, and they removed mysql ok (apart from the first line which it seems needed to be `apt-get remove --purge 'mysql-.*'`, but then it re-installed the latest version again instead of the older version that I was after.

Comment: I got there cheers. The first half is as you suggested, the second half is slightly different,

Comment: I'll take a closer look, but whenever I have run it the only options are for MySQL 8.0 (latest version) or MySQL 5.7 (latest version) as well as a few other options such as with or without Cluster.